# C++11, shared_ptr.reset() and cyclic references

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, reset, cyclic-reference

I have a question about the behaviour of shared_ptr.reset().

In this scenario I have a cyclic reference with the following classes. I have a book and an owner, which both have std::shared_ptrs to each other, creating a cyclic reference.

Book.h

```
#pragma once

class Owner;

class Book
{
public:
    Book(std::string title);
    ~Book();
    void OutputDetails();
    void SetOwner(std::shared_ptr<Owner> owner);
    void OutputOwnerInformation();
private:
    std::string m_title;
    std::shared_ptr<Owner> m_owner; // Book hangs onto the owner and creates a circular dependency
};
```

Book.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Book.h"
#include "Owner.h"

Book::Book(std::string title) : m_title(title) {}

Book::~Book() {
    std::cout << "Book Destroyed" << std::endl;
}

void Book::SetOwner(std::shared_ptr<Owner> owner) {
    m_owner = owner; // strong reference
}

void Book::OutputOwnerInformation() {
    std::cout << "Owner is: " << m_owner->GetName() << std::endl;
}

void Book::OutputOwnerInformation() {
    std::cout << "Owner is: " << m_owner->GetName() << std::endl;
}
```

Owner.h

```
#pragma once

class Book; // To avoid circular #includes

class Owner
{
public:
    Owner(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Book> book);
    ~Owner();
    void OutputDetails();
    std::string GetName();
private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::shared_ptr<Book> m_book; // Owner hangs onto the book
};
```

Owner.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Owner.h"
#include "Book.h"

Owner::Owner(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Book> book) : m_name(name), m_book(book) {}

Owner::~Owner() {
    std::cout << "Owner Destroyed" << std::endl;
}

void Owner::OutputDetails() {
    std::cout << m_name << " owns " << std::endl;
    m_book->OutputDetails();
}

std::string Owner::GetName() {
    return m_name;
}
```

Here is the main.cpp. In this case, book and owner have strong references to each other and will memory leak once _tmain exits its scope. The destructors for both book and owner are not called when I insert breakpoints in the respective destructors.

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include "Book.h"
#include "Owner.h"

int _tmain(int, _TCHAR*)
{
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Book> book = std::shared_ptr<Book>(new Book("Moby Dick"));
        std::shared_ptr<Owner> owner = std::shared_ptr<Owner>(new Owner("George Heriot", book));

        // Introduced a circular dependency so
        // neither gets deleted
        book->SetOwner(owner);

        owner->OutputDetails();
        book->OutputOwnerInformation();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to see if I could reset() the pointers such that the destructor was called and to break the cyclic dependency. According to my understanding of shared_ptr.reset(), the object should become empty.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/reset/

However, my break points in both destructors are not being hit. My assumption would be that because I have reset both book and owner, the reference count would drop to 0 for both and they would be destroyed when _tmain returns.

main2.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include "Book.h"
#include "Owner.h"

int _tmain(int, _TCHAR*)
{
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Book> book = std::shared_ptr<Book>(new Book("Moby Dick"));
        std::shared_ptr<Owner> owner = std::shared_ptr<Owner>(new Owner("George Heriot", book));

        // Introduced a circular dependency so
        // neither gets deleted
        book->SetOwner(owner);

        owner->OutputDetails();
        book->OutputOwnerInformation();

        owner.reset();
        book.reset();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that this is already horrible code and I could use a weak_ptr to remove the cyclic dependency but I am just curious why reset() does not break this dependency.

Comment: But you are not breaking the loop, `book.m_owner` is still pointing to the owner, and `owner.m_book` is still pointing to the book. I think you may be thinking that the shared pointers from main and the ones from your objects are the same, but they are not: they just _point_ to the same objects and share the reference count.

Comment: If you have cyclic ownership, by definition you have a design error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try printing `owner.use_count()` and `book.use_count()` before resetting them. You'll see the use counts are 2. The reset calls will make `owner` and `book` decrement their counts by 1, but there are still other `shared_ptr` objects that share ownership with them and which you don't reset, so the reference counts don't reach zero.

If you think about it you should realise that of course `reset()` can't break cycles, because the equivalent of `reset()` happens in the `shared_ptr` destructor anyway. If the destructor could break cycles like that then there would be no problem creating cycles in the first place.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I understand what is going on now.

In this case, since I have reset both owner and book, are there wild instances of Book and Owner somewhere in memory?

Comment: No, they're not "wild" the shared_ptr `owner->m_book` shares ownership with `book` and `book->m_owner` shares ownership with `owner`. You have only reset `owner` not `m_book->owner`. When you reset `owner` the refcount goes to 1 and you cannot reset the last shared_ptr because you'd just thrown away the only handle you had to it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that. 

I meant wild in the sense that, I have lost my only handle to `owner` and `book` in _tmain when I do `owner.reset()` and `book.reset()` so I cannot retrieve a handle to `owner` and `book`.